# Custom ListView is not updated when items are inserted

Tags: java, android

I have a custom listview with custom adapter extending BaseAdapter if i add items to this list view in OnCreate method they show up in list, but if i add them from other methods like a packet listener method then items do not show up , on the screen below this listview there is a textbox if i select textbox to entertext using virtual keyboard immediately the listview gets populated with previousely inserted items which didnt show up. This activity is a chat window basically
I have tried calling notifyDataSetChanged, invalidate on Layout or on listview but nothing helped.

What i think is i need to have a way to refresh activity , as same thing must be happening when the virtual keyboard pops up .

Help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Code:

package com.arounds;

public class ChatActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,PacketListener{

```
 private ListView chatView;  
 private ChatListViewCustomAdapter adapter; 
 private String user;
 private XMPPConnection connection;
 private Conversation conv;
 private ChatActivity selfRef = this;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.chat_win);

        AroundApplication app = (AroundApplication) this.getApplicationContext();
        connection = app.getConnection();

        chatView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.conversationList);  
        adapter = new ChatListViewCustomAdapter(this);  
        chatView.setAdapter(adapter); 

        // set send btn listener
        ImageButton send = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSend);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton smiley = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSmiley);
        smiley.setOnClickListener(this);
        // get the parameter passed by previouse activity

        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        String temp = b.getString("user");
        user = temp;

        TextView v = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle_chat);
        v.setText(temp);

        v = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription_chat);
        temp = b.getString("status");
        v.setText(temp);
        //chatView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        HashMap convs = app.getConversations();

        if(convs.containsKey(user) == true)
            conv = (Conversation) convs.get(user);
        else {
            conv = new Conversation();
            convs.put(user,conv);
        }

        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(this,filter);


 }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.imgBtnSend)
    {
    EditText msg = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editChat);
    String s = msg.getText().toString();
     Message message = new Message(user, Message.Type.chat);
     message.setBody(s);
     connection.sendPacket(message);

     ArrayList<ChatMessage> m = conv.messages;
     String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()); 

     m.add(new ChatMessage(s,currentDate));

     adapter.addItem("I said",s,currentDate,Constants.SEND_LIST_TYPE);
     //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        //View view = this.findViewById(R.id.linerLayoutChat);
        chatView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


@Override
public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("in");
      Message message = (Message) packet;
      if (message.getBody() != null) {

          System.out.println("in1");
            String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
            ArrayList<ChatMessage> m = conv.messages;
            String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()); 

            m.add(new ChatMessage(message.getBody(),currentDate));

            adapter.addItem(fromName+" said",message.getBody(),currentDate,Constants.REC_LIST_TYPE);

            //chatView.postInvalidate();
      }
}
```

}

Adapter class:

```
public class ChatListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
public ArrayList<ChatListItem> items;
public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;
public Boolean temp=false;

public ChatListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context) {
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.items = new ArrayList<ChatListItem>();
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{

    TextView txtViewTitle;
    TextView txtViewDescription;
    TextView txtViewDate;
}
public void addItem(String title,String desc,String d,int type)
{
    ChatListItem item = new ChatListItem(title,desc,d,type);
    items.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ChatListItem item = items.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    System.out.println("Title:"+item.title+" type:"+item.type);
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        int type = this.getItemViewType(position);
        if(type == 0)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_even, null);
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitleEven);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescriptionEven);
            holder.txtViewDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDateEven);

        }
        else
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_odd, null);
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitleOdd);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescriptionOdd);
            holder.txtViewDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDateOdd);

        }


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();


    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(item.title);
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(item.desc);
    holder.txtViewDate.setText(item.date);

    return convertView;
} 
 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     ChatListItem item = items.get(position);
     return item.type;
 }
 @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return 2;
  }
```

}

Comment: You will need to show some code before anyone can help you for your question. My guess, you are perhaps missing a notifyDatasetChanged call.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work, re-set the adapter on the `ListView` by calling `ListView.setAdapter()` with the same `Adapter` again. This should refresh the view.

Comment: tried this but didnt help , is there any issue related with Listener method and GUI thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Handle all the updates within your Adapter and ensure you invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you update it (within your Adapter)?

Comment: I have said it already that it works fron oncreate and i am calling notifyDataSetChanged method

Comment: So are you "Handling all the updates within your Adapter"? and calling 'notifyDataSetChanged()' at its end? Or is there somewhere you are explicitly calling the Adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() from outside it (or more likely not)?

Comment: i am adding items to arraylist inside adapter and then calling notifydatasetchanged there only

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I can see not right are these methods:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

These methods should return proper values.

items.get(position) and position respectively.

Comment: did it , but i dont thik it will really matter, as still there is no use , still listview is not updated when i receive message

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any exception in your processPacket method? I don't see anything wrong with the code. Try putting some Log message in your addItem method, and see, if the messages are really getting added to the adapter.

Comment: thanks, they are definitely getting added just are not getting displayed , proof is when i click on a list item or try to enter some text into text box which is at the bottom of the listview the list gets refreshed and recived items get displayed so i am sure processPacket method works fine without any exception

Comment: Ahh.. Is there any way you could upload a sample project by modifying your code a little bit?